# Factoring Polynomials Completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, factors

I am relativly new to Python and I decided to try to write code that would factor any polynomial using the Rational Root Theorem and synthetic division. I have two questions.

1. Is there any way I can clean up my code or any common practices that I should know about?
2. How could I allow my function to factor polynomials with two or more factors that are not binomials? If this is not possible without significant modification to my code, then just let me know without going into the details.

My program takes a user input for the coefficients of the polynomial. If the polynomial has no term of the degree requested, type '0'. The output is a string that contains the factors in a format like:

> \$3(2x - 1)(2x + 1)(9x^2 + 4x + 4)\$

My code is below:

```
from fractions import Fraction
def gcf(numbers):
    gcf = 1
    abs_numbers = [abs(i) for i in numbers]
    large = max(abs_numbers)
    if numbers[0] >= 0:
        for i in range(large, 1, -1):
            if all(number % i == 0 for number in abs_numbers) == True:
                gcf = i
                break
    else:
        for i in range(-large, -1):
            if all(number % i == 0 for number in abs_numbers) == True:
                gcf = i
                break
    return gcf
def factors(x):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, abs(int(x)) + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors
def remove_duplicates(input):
    output = []
    for x in input:
        if x not in output:
            output.append(x)
    return output
def fractions(lista, listb):
    fractions = []
    lista = [float(i) for i in lista]
    listb = [float(i) for i in listb]
    for i in lista:
        for j in listb:
            fractions.extend([i / j, -i / j])
    fractions = remove_duplicates(fractions)
    return(fractions)
def synthetic_division(coefficients, divisor):
    results = [float(coefficients[0])]
    for i in range(len(coefficients) - 1):
        results.append(results[-1] * divisor + coefficients[i + 1])
    return(results)
def factor1(coefficients):
    factors_leading = factors(coefficients[0])
    factors_constant = factors(coefficients[-1])
    possible_roots = fractions(factors_constant, factors_leading)
    for i in possible_roots:
        results = synthetic_division(coefficients, i)
        if results[-1] == 0:
            results.pop(-1)
            return([-i, results])
            break
    else:
        return False
def factor(coefficients):
    gcf1 = gcf(coefficients)
    coefficients = [coefficient / gcf1 for coefficient in coefficients]
    polynomial = coefficients
    roots = []
    while factor1(polynomial) != False:
        roots.append(factor1(polynomial)[0])
        polynomial = factor1(polynomial)[1]
    polynomial = [int(term) for term in polynomial]
    gcf2 = gcf(polynomial)
    polynomial = [term / gcf2 for term in polynomial]
    for i in range(len(roots)):
        if roots[i] % 1 != 0:
            numerator = []
            denominator = []
            slash = False
            for j in str(Fraction(roots[i]).limit_denominator()):
                if j == '/':
                    slash = True
                if slash == False:
                    numerator.append(j)
                elif j == '/':
                    pass
                else:
                    denominator.append(j)
            frac = (int("".join(numerator)), int("".join(denominator)))
            roots[i] = (frac[1], frac[0])
        else:
            roots[i] = (1, int(roots[i]))
    if gcf1 == 1:
        answer = []
    else:
        answer = [str(gcf1)]
    for i in roots:
        answer.append("(%sx + %s)" % (i[0], i[1]))
    string = ["("]
    for i in range(len(polynomial)):
        if i == len(polynomial) - 2:
            string.append("%sx + " % (polynomial[i]))
        elif i == len(polynomial) - 1:
            string.append("%s" % (polynomial[i]))
        else:
            string.append("%sx^%s + " % (polynomial[i], len(polynomial) - i - 1))
    string.append(")")
    string = "".join(string)
    if len(polynomial) > 1:
        answer.append(string)
    answer = "".join(answer)
    return(answer)
term_number = int(raw_input("How many terms are in your polynomial? "))
coefficients = []
coefficients.append(int(raw_input("What is the highest degree term's coefficient? ")))
for i in range(term_number - 2):
coefficients.append(int(raw_input("What is the next highest degree term's coefficient? ")))
coefficients.append(int(raw_input("What is the constant? ")))
print(factor(coefficients))
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6):

#### Coding style

There's a standard for coding style in Python called [PEP8](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
I suggest to go through it and follow it.

#### Don't use a variable if you don't need one

In the `gcf` function, there is a variable called `gcf`,
the same as the function name,
which can be confusing.
Luckily there's no need for it, you can easily remove all references to it:

```
def gcf(numbers):
    abs_numbers = [abs(i) for i in numbers]
    large = max(abs_numbers)
    if numbers[0] >= 0:
        for i in range(large, 1, -1):
            if all(number % i == 0 for number in abs_numbers) == True:
                return i
    else:
        for i in range(-large, -1):
            if all(number % i == 0 for number in abs_numbers) == True:
                return i
    return 1
```

#### Avoid duplicated logic

Notice that the loops in both branches of the `if-else` are the same except the range. You can reduce code duplication by first putting the range into a variable, and then perform the loop:

```
def gcf(numbers):
    abs_numbers = [abs(i) for i in numbers]
    large = max(abs_numbers)
    if numbers[0] >= 0:
        num_range = range(large, 1, -1)
    else:
        num_range = range(-large, -1)

    for i in num_range:
        if all(number % i == 0 for number in abs_numbers) == True:
            return i
    return 1
```

#### Use boolean expressions directly

Instead of:

> ```
> if all(number % i == 0 for number in abs_numbers) == True:
> ```

You can use a boolean expression directly, without `== True`:

```
if all(number % i == 0 for number in abs_numbers):
```

#### Use list comprehensions

This function can be rewritten in a more compact way using list comprehensions:

> ```
> def factors(x):
>     factors = []
>     for i in range(1, abs(int(x)) + 1):
>         if x % i == 0:
>             factors.append(i)
>     return factors
> ```

Like this:

```
def factors(x):
    return [i for i in range(1, abs(int(x)) + 1) if x % i == 0]
```

#### Odd breaks

A few odd things in this bit of code:

> ```
> for i in possible_roots:
>     results = synthetic_division(coefficients, i)
>     if results[-1] == 0:
>         results.pop(-1)
>         return([-i, results])
>         break
> else:
>     return False
> ```

The `break` after a `return` is pointless.
And if there is no other statement in a function after the `for ... else`,
then you can rewrite without the `else`, which is simpler:

```
for i in possible_roots:
    results = synthetic_division(coefficients, i)
    if results[-1] == 0:
        results.pop(-1)
        return([-i, results])
return False
```

But, another thing that's really not good here is that the function returns two kinds of values: it can be list or it can be boolean.
This is going to be confusing and hard to use for callers.
I suggest to rethink the design,
make all functions return one kind of value, not more.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot here. The two most important critiques I have are:

1. calling `factors1` three times with the same arguments
2. using floating point numbers instead of `Fraction` objects

## removing duplicates

Your code is fine.  There is support for this operation
in the `more_itertools` library, see [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](//stackoverflow.com/a/17016257/866915)

## gcf

The gcf of two numbers may be computed more efficiently by using the
Euclidean algorithm.

The gcf of a list of numbers may be computed like this:

```
def gcf(nums):
  a = nums[0]
  for b in nums[1:]:
     a = gcf0(a,b)   # gcf0 is the Euclidean algorithm
  return a
```

The already imported [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) library  has an implementation of the
Euclidean algorithm called `gcd`.

## fractions

You are testing floating point numbers as possible roots of
your polynomial. Floating point arithmetic is inexact, and so
it is possible that due to round off error you will miss a root.
It is better to use the exact arithmetic that the `Fraction` class
gives you.

Also, the name `fractions` is very overloaded: you are importing
a module named `fractions`, you have a list named `fractions`
and a function named `fractions`. Having a different name
for each of these will make your code more readable.

Finally, learn more about list comprehensions – they will
make your life easier:

```
def all_ratios(lista, listb):
  ratios = [ Fraction(a,b) for a in list a for b in list b ]
  return ratios.extend( [ -x for x in ratios ] )
```

## factors

Another place where a list comprehension could be used:

```
def factors(x):
    return [ d for d in xrange(1,x+1) if x % d == 0 ]
```

## factors1

You are calling `factors1` THREE times with the same parameters:

```
while factor1(polynomial) != False:
    roots.append(factor1(polynomial)[0])
    polynomial = factor1(polynomial)[1]
```

You should just call it once, save the result in a variable
and use the variable for the other two calls. I.e.:

```
while True:
  result = factor1(polynomial)
  if result != False:
    break
  roots.append( result[0] )
  polynomial = result[1]
  ...
```

## use the Fraction class

Example:

```
z = Fraction(6,4)  # create the exact Fraction 6/4 ( = 3/2)
print z.numerator, z.denominator  # prints: 3 2
```

You can also do arithmetic (+, -, *, /) with Fraction objects:

```
w = Fraction(1,7) + 2*z + z*z
print w   # "151/28"
```

When printing out the result in `factors` you have the expression:

```
 str(Fraction(roots[i]).limit_denominator()):
```

and a complex for loop to figure out what the numerator
and demoninator are.

No doubt you found you needed to add the `.limit_denominator()`
because `roots[i]` is a floating point number. If `roots[i]` were
already a `Fraction` you could just use:

```
frac = ( roots[i].numerator, roots[i].denominator )
```

and avoid the for loop.